# Div com z-index superior anula outra div com z-indez inferior

Tags: html, css

Tenho 2 divs.
A primeira tem o z-index 1 e position fixed.
A segunda div tem o z-index 2 e position relative.

A segunda div tem um conteúdo muito extenso e entre os conteúdos, existe uma parte em branco com 500px de altura.
Ao passar por essa parte em branco, o conteúdo da primeira div é revelado, porém tenho um botão e não consigo clicar nesse botão.

No CSS da segunda div coloquei o seguinte código, porém os botões da segunda div deixaram de funcionar.

```
pointer-events: none
```

Como faço para invalidar o espaço branco da segunda div de modo que seja possível clicar no botão que está primeira div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas acredito que você possa usar esse css:

.botao-click{
  pointer-events: auto;
}

"botao-click" seria a classe do botão.

*EDIT

Fiz umas alterações no seu jsfiddle, veja aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/s0kvg269/.
Basicamente eu coloquei o .d1 dentro do .d2, tirei o position: absolute do .d2, e o .conteudo que tampa o .d1 eu deixei com position: relative.

Comment: aqui tem um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/5LfhffrL/ faz o scroll para baixo, vai aparecer uma div vermelha, tenta clicar no "botão 1" ou no "botão 2", vai perceber o que estou dizendo.

Comment: Editei o comentário, acho que agora ficou como o esperado.